# Anonymous access to REST API - without using Sites?

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, rest

I'm looking for a way to enable public/anonymous access to my REST API developed using APEX without using Sites. The reason for this is that Sites is only available in Enterprise and not in Professional. I'm not sure it is possible.

I have been looking around a lot and among other things found Wade Wegners great article of how to enable it anonymously using sites: 
http://www.wadewegner.com/2013/03/creating-anonymous-rest-apis-with-salesforce-com/

Comment: I really doubt that this is possible however you can create a heroku app with credentials to connect to sales force and expose salesforce's rest api using that app. The heroku app can internally authenticate with salesforce using Username and password and perform required operation. Be advised that it will expose your data to everyone however you may put something like secret code in your heroku app and by controlling the Login User's profile settings.

Comment: I have verified that method suggested by Wade Wegners works, but does this fulfill best practices? I am planning to use same for an ISV app. Please advise.